# Como puedo leer datos de un archivo en Shiny? R-Studion (Resuelto)

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

estoy haciendo un dashboard con shiny y me gustaria hacer varios graficos pero no se como escribir el codigo para que de la informacion de un archivo me cree los graficos. He visto en muchos lugares como hacer para crear un boton para subir los archivos pero no es lo que quiero. Lo que quiero nada mas es poder usar los datos de la forma usual que se haria si no estuviera usando shiny. Es decir poder usar read.csv() para crear los graficos.

Adjunto un extracto del codigo que estoy usando

```
Server

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(zoo)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df1.1.1=data.frame(read_excel("C:/Users/.../Base.xlsx", sheet = "1.1.1"))
  df1.1.1$mes.y.año = as.yearmon(as.Date(df1.1.1$mes.y.año, origin="1899-12-30"))

  output$admision_iden_grap <- renderPlot({


    plot(df1.1.1$mes.y.año, (1-(df1.1.1$errores/df1.1.1$egresos))*100,  ylim= c(0,100), type ="h")

  })

})

UI

library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  hr(),

    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("Pagina principal", tabName="principal", icon=icon("pagelines"), selected=TRUE),
                menuItem("Metas internacionales de seguridad", icon=icon("chart-bar"),
                    menuSubItem("Identificacion", tabName = "identificacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                    menuSubItem("Comunicacion", tabName = "comunicacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                    menuSubItem("Medicamentos", tabName = "medicamentos", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                    menuSubItem("Cirugias", tabName = "cirugias", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                    menuSubItem("Infecciones", tabName = "infecciones", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                    menuSubItem("Caidas", tabName = "caidas", icon = icon("angle-right"))
                        ),
                menuItem("Procesos", tabName = "procesos", icon=icon("chart-bar")),
                menuItem("Tiempos", tabName = "tiempos", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
                menuItem("Manual", tabName = "manual", icon=icon("mortar-board")),
                menuItem("Acerca de", tabName = "acerca", icon = icon("question"))
                ),width = 285

                          )

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "principal",
            withMathJax(), 
            includeMarkdown("principal.Rmd")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "admision_iden",
            dateRangeInput('admision_fecha',
                           label = 'Por favor seleccionar fecha:',
                           start = Sys.Date() - 2, end = Sys.Date() + 2, format = "mm yyyy", startview = 'year', language = 'es'
                          ), 

            column(width = 8,
                   box(  width = NULL, plotOutput(outputId = "admision_iden_grap"), collapsible = TRUE,
                         title = "Plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE)
                  )
            )
          ))



dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Indicadores HCB", titleWidth=285),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

El error que me aparece es este

```
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://###.0.0.1:####

Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box

Warning in checkEncoding(file) :
  The input file C:\Users\....\Prueba/server.R does not seem to be encoded in UTF8
Warning in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:\.../server.R'
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  C:\.../server.R:11:0: unexpected end of input
9:   df1.1.1=data.frame(read_excel("C:/Users/.../Base.xlsx", sheet = "1.1.1"))
10:   df1.1.1$mes.y.a
   ^
Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbMkRB\file42c486c4a65
  [No stack trace available]
Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) : 
  Error sourcing C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbMkRB\file42c486c4a65
```

Comment: Se resolvió guardando los archivos con codificacion UTF8.

Comment: Que bueno que ya resolviste el problema. Te sugiero que no uses la dirección fija de los archivos en Shiny "C:/Users/.../Base.xlsx" en cambio podrías guardarlos en la carpeta donde tienes tu archivo ui.R y server.R o en su defecto app.R y entonces podrías cargarlos usando solamente la dirección relativa "Base.xlsx". Saludos!